# Making "dictionary"

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

I have a lot of code I wrote, for various different projects.

I want to save them in 1 file, to have like a "repository" of working code modules. So for new VBA projects I can copy the modules from there.

Is there a way to save the code files outside of the VBA editor? Like a text file or something like that?

Comment: You can right-click on any module and export it to a text file.  Or use a tool such as MZTools which has a "code library" feature.

Comment: @Close-Voters: this question is in no way asking about a tool or book or other off-site resource. It is about features of the Visual Basic Editor, the IDE for VBA - IDE questions are perfectly on-topic. The "tool" part is in no way central to the question, and was edited out.

Comment: Can't find the option to export to a txt file. Only to the vba format.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Simply select **Export File...** from the *Project Explorer* toolwindow:

[image: vanilla functionality]

If you're using [Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) (disclaimer: I manage this OSS project), you can also do that from the *Code Explorer* toolwindow:

[image: Rubberduck functionality]

To use the exported module(s) in other VBA projects, you'll need to **Import** it back. You can do that one file at a time with the VBE's *Project Explorer*, or all files at once with Rubberduck's *Code Explorer*.

Or you can simply drag-and-drop the files into the *Project Explorer*.

Standard modules will have a .bas file extension; Class modules will have .cls; UserForm modules will have a .frm file and likely a .frx binary that needs to be in the same folder as the .frm for it to import back correctly.

Document modules (e.g. workbook and worksheet modules, like `Sheet1` and `ThisWorkbook`) can't be imported, but you can export them as .cls files from the *Project Explorer*, or as .doccls files from Rubberduck.

The reason Rubberduck exports document modules with a different file extension, is because they can't be imported back, so module and member attributes (which you can only discover by opening the exported files in a text editor e.g. Notepad++) can't be tweaked the same way normal class modules can.